# Microsoft sql studio, ASP.net multiple where

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I need to get data from this database.
I need second maximum. I have been trying do it with double where but it didn't work, i really don't know what should I use.

```
select * 
from [database] 
where [ID]=
(
    select max([ID])-1  
    from [database] 
    where [section]=1
)

ID|text|section|
1 |xxxx|   1   |
2 |xxxx|   2   |
3 |xxxx|   2   |
4 |xxxx|   1   |
5 |xxxx|   4   |
6 |xxxx|   1   |
```

I am using asp.net so its little harder. 
From this table I need SECOND maximum of 1. section.
I was trying "AND" command but it doesn't work. I am new to SQL and ASP. 
I think for first I need find 1. section and then second maximum with this section something like

```
if(section==1&&secmaximum)
{
.
.
.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `ROW_NUMBER()` here:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE section = 1
) t
WHERE rn = 2;
```

If the possibility for ties exist, then you might want to use a rank function instead of row number.  In that case, maybe the 2nd highest rank is what you would want.